# Create new record from sale order with product order in Odoo

Tags: python, methods, odoo, odoo-10

I want to create recordset with product in my custom class from sale order after calling an event. I will create a record in sale.order and like creating invoice, I will create record in my custom module.

What I have done is:
In my custom class:

```
class LoadingSlip(models.Model):
    _name = 'loading.slip'
    _description = 'loading information'
    partner_id = fields.Char("Customer Name")
    order_date = fields.Date("Order Date")
    expiration_date = fields.Date("Expiration Date")
    # order_line = fields.One2many('sale.order.line', 'order_id', string="Order Lines")
    product_line = fields.One2many('loading.product.line', 'loading_product', string="Loading Products")

class LoadingProduct(models.Model):
    _name = 'loading.product.line'
    _description = "Loading Product Informations"
    products_id = fields.Many2one('product.product', string='Product',
        ondelete='restrict', index=True)
    quantity = fields.Float(string='Quantity', default=1)
    loading_product = fields.Many2one('loading.slip', string="Loading Reference", ondelete='cascade', index='True')
```

In sale.order

```
class sale_func(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'

    @api.multi
    def _prepare_slip(self):
        test.set_trace()
        self.ensure_one()
        slip = {
            'partner_id': self.partner_id.name,
            'order_date': self.date_order,
            'expiration_date': self.validity_date,
        }
        return slip

    @api.multi
    def action_slip_create(self, grouped=False, final=False):
        test.set_trace() # debug point
        pprint(self)
        inv_obj = self.env['loading.slip']
        precision = self.env['decimal.precision'].precision_get('Product Unit of Measure')
        slips={}
        pprint(slips)
        slipReferences={}
        test.set_trace()
        for order in self:
            group_key = order.id
            test.set_trace()
            for line in order.order_line:
                if group_key not in slips:
                    inv_data = order._prepare_slip()
                    loadingslip = inv_obj.create(inv_data)
                    slipReferences[loadingslip] = order
                    slips[group_key] = loadingslip                
                if line.product_uom_qty > 0:
                    line.slip_line_create(slips[group_key].id)

        if not slips:
            raise UserError(_('There is no loading slip line.'))

    @api.multi
    def create_slip(self):
        test.set_trace()
        pprint(self)
        sale_orders = self.env['sale.order'].browse(self._context.get('active_ids', []))
        self.action_slip_create(sale_orders)
```

In sale.order.line

```
class sales_order(models.Model):
    _inherit="sale.order.line"

    @api.multi
    def _prepare_slip_line(self):
        test.set_trace()
        self.ensure_one()
        res={}
        pprint(res)
        res={
            'products_id': self.product_id.id or False,
            'quantity': self.product_uom_qty
        }
        pprint(res)

    @api.multi
    def slip_line_create(self, loading_product):
        test.set_trace()
        prdct_order = self.env['loading.product.line']
        for line in self:
            vals = line._prepare_slip_line()
            prdct_order.create(vals)
```

My error is:

```
> /home/diwap/odoo-dev/custom-addons/sales_ext_agni/models/models.py(196)slip_line_create()
    195             vals = line._prepare_slip_line()
--> 196             prdct_order.create(vals)
    197

ipdb> n
TypeError: "argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable"
```

I have tried update and write method instead of create in line 196 but I could not get any result it's just come up with an empty field and also no error. However when I try the real thing and i.e. write() I get this error. Is there any wrong somewhere in my code or its just an horrible thing I am doing.

Comment: According to your code, `_prepare_slip_line` does not return anything. All you do is create the dict `res` and pprint it. By default, Python functions without `return` return `None`. Have you tried returning `res`?

Comment: I did that and my problem of nonetype is fixed but still I am not getting record yet